# unable to customized background color based on ItemName in angular2-multiselect-dropdown

Tags: angular, npm

Does angular2-multiselect-dropdown support the customized background color based on the tags label.

Need the background color based on the tags label.

This is the npm of the package but there is no description about it https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-multiselect-dropdown

[image]

Suggestion is appreciated for this pulgin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use there templating [example](https://cuppalabs.github.io/angular2-multiselect-dropdown/#/templating) something like

```
<angular2-multiselect [data]="itemList" [(ngModel)]="selectedItems" [settings]="settings" (onSelect)="onItemSelect($event)" (onDeSelect)="OnItemDeSelect($event)"  (onSelectAll)="onSelectAll($event)" (onDeSelectAll)="onDeSelectAll($event)">
<c-badge>
<ng-template let-item="item">
    <label style="margin: 0px;" [style.backgroundColor]="item.color">{{item.itemName}}</label>
</ng-template>
</c-badge>
</angular2-multiselect>
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular2-multiselect-dropdown-sdyehz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)